# sklearnのTfidfVectorizerについて

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

`sklearn`でKMeansを利用しようと考えています。
https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch03/rel_post_20news.py
上記のサンプルを参考にしています。
上記サンプルの[L58](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch03/rel_post_20news.py#L58)で`TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()`で学習データをベクトル化し、[L91](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch03/rel_post_20news.py#L91)で新しいクラスタリング対象のデータを`TfidfVectorizer.transform()`でベクトル化しています。

これは、必ず`fit_transform()`を呼び出してから`transform()`を呼びださなければならないのでしょうか。
もしそうなら、`fit_transform()`した状態を保存しておき新しい対象に対しては`fit_transform()`を省略することはできるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

学習データのベクトル化と、新しいデータのベクトル化は独立した操作なので、必ずしもfit_transform()を呼び出してからtransform()を呼びなさないといけないわけではありません。fit_transform()で作られたベクトルをディスクに保存しておけば、後からロードすることができます。

`vectorized`の型は`scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`なので`.toarray()`でnumpyの形式に変換してから保存すればいいと思います。復元はその逆の操作になります。

```
import numpy
import scipy.sparse.csr

# vectorizedはgithubの例にあるようにvectorizer.fit_transform(...)で得られたもの

# 保存
numpy.save('my_vector', vectorized.toarray())

# 復元 なぜかファイル名は拡張子をつけないとロードできない
vectorized2 = scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix(numpy.load('my_vector.npy'))

# 値の同一性の確認
print (vectorized.toarray() == vectorized2.toarray()).all()
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。`numpy.save()`で保存できるところまでは調べられていましたが、`toarray`で`numpy`形式に変換するところと、`csr_matrix`でscipy形式に変換するところを忘れていました。